# sum 2 rows with different variables dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following tbl_df;

```
V1    V2
abc   39
12bc  15
87gd  3
987   50
```

Happened that variable `abc` and variable `12bc` mean the same thing. I would like to run a dplyr script to add the values on `V2` to combine both rows, hide or delete the previous rows and create a new one. The tbl_df would end up like the following:

```
V1    V2
abc   54 => where abc is the sum of previous abc and 12bc
87gd  3
987   50
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: How would one know that `abc` and `12bc` mean the same thing- is it *only* those two you want to combine, or are you combining a larger collection of pairs (or groups) of values?

Comment: abc has a meaning in an old description and changed to 12bc in  a new revision.

Comment: Do you have a lookup table for this kind of match up? Or is it only 1 case of abc to 12bc?

Comment: That's not what I mean: I mean, is this the *only* pair you want to combine? (If so it's straightforward just to replace that one value). Did nothing else change? If more than one change happened, you must have some kind of "table" for what should be combined.

Comment: Are around 6 instances that I have to add up. I have to look at a book to verify the meaning.

Comment: I want to avoid to add or sum by hand.

Comment: For each of these instances, replace the value of one of the levels, like `df$V1[df$V1 == "12bc"] <- "abc"`, then perform the aggregation. Since you only have around 6 instances, this is probably the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use plyr, this could work!

```
new_df <- old_df %>%
    mutate(V1 = ifelse(V1 == "12bc", "abc", V1) %>%
    group_by(V1) %>%
    summarise(V2 = sum(v2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this in two steps: first replacing the "old" V1 values with the new values, then grouping by V1 and summarizing.

The `plyr` package has a `revalue` function you can use to replace values. First create a vector with *all* the replacements you want (if it's only six, as you specify in your comment, this shouldn't be a problem)

```
replacements <- c("12bc" = "abc")  # put other pairs in, separated by commas
```

You can then revalue and group in the same step before summarizing:

```
newdata <- mydata %>%
  group_by(V1 = plyr::revalue(V1, replacements)) %>%
  summarize(V2 = sum(V2))
```

Note that this assumes you don't have any columns other than V1 and V2. If you do, you'll need to specify how they get summarized (what if they're different between the old and new versions?)

Comment: `dplyr::summarise()`...does `plyr::summarise()` care about `group_by`?

Comment: @Dambo no, but I'm not doing `library(plyr)`. Instead I'm specifying `plyr::revalue` (which does not load plyr into the namespace), which is a good practice when using both

Comment: Thanks, this is something I'll keep in mind when using only a couple of functions from a library

Comment: By the way, is there any way to pass additional arguments to `group_by` and refactor on the fly?

Comment: @DavidRobinson | This script returns one value. I need to keep the tbl_df. I need to be able to make the calculation, keep the entire df and replace the two rows with the new row and the new value. Like I show  above.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré recode requires that each recoding be given as a separate argument in `...`, not as a vector. I think this ends up crowding the dplyr chain (it would take up more space than the rest of the logic); when there are more than (say) 2 or 3 encodings I like defining them in advance

Comment: @DavidRobinson Oh, right. I didn't read the comment where OP mentions he has *6 instances*.